# Insertion into map in c++

Tags: c++, data-structures, hashtable

So, I was going through code on geeksforgeeks for checking which array is lesser of two given arrays.
I came across this code snippet and is confused about the usage of the maps.

```
   map<int, int> mp1; 

   for (int i = 0; i < m; i++) 
       mp1[a[i]]++;
```

Here `a[i]` is the array given and `m` is the size of the array.

So, Here how they have used map to insert array elements and if so what would be the key values.

Comment: *I came across this code snippet* -- That site you mentioned is not one to get code snippets from, since most of the sample code there is poor.  Their explanation of some algorithmic concepts are better, but the code that goes along with the explanation, that's a different story.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::map::operator[]` will insert the element if it doesn't already exist.

See https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/operator_at

Comment: Thanks for this one more doubt I have so what would be their key values or maybe like while accessing how do we go about that. Would be thankful for the information.

Comment: @MostLovedPotato That's all explained on the page I linked to. *Read* it.

Comment: Note that this is unique to the associative containers of the standard library. Those containers have extra code to add missing elements. Other types like arrays, `std::vector`, `std::string`, `std::deque` with `operator[]` *won't* insert elements if the index is out of bounds.

Comment: Thanks for the info.